# Converting a language specification into production rules (not sure if it's a CFG or CSG)

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, context-sensitive-grammar, chomsky-hierarchy

I have to write a function that checks whether input strings are valid for a given language specification. I thought that this would be a standard CFG -> Chomsky Normal Form, then CYK parsing, but one of the rules in the language is preventing this from happening.

Some of the rules are straightforward, if we define terminals `{a,b,c,d,e,f,P,Q,R,S}`, then valid strings are

> 1) Any of the lowercase terminals in isolation
>   2) If 'x' is a valid string, then so is Sx

But the third rule is

> 3) If X and Y are valid input strings, then so are PXY, QXY, RXY

where `{P,Q,R}` are the remaining uppercase terminals and X and Y are nonterminals.

What would the production rule for this look like? I thought it would be something like

```
XY -> PXY (and QXY, RXY)
```

but there are two problems with this. The first is that this is not a CFG rule -- does that mean this language defines a CSG instead?

And the second is that this doesn't work, because

> XY -> PXY -> PPXY

would not be a valid message in all cases.

Comment: Start asking such questions on [CSTheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this grammar is context-free, unless I'm misinterpreting what you're saying.

First, let's let A be the nonterminal that expands out to some valid string made just using the first two rules, we get

```
A -> a | b | c | d | e | f
```

Now, your second rule says that if you can build the string ω then you can build Sω.  We could encode that as

```
A -> SA
```

Finally, you've said that if you have two strings X and Y, then you can combine them together as

```
PXY
QXY
RXY
```

One way to think about this would be to generate the string P, followed by any two valid strings (same for Q or R).  Thus you could add the rules

```
A -> PAA | QAA | RAA
```

This gives the final grammar

```
A -> a | b | c | d | e | f
A -> SA
A -> PAA | QAA | RAA
```

Hope this helps!